# hibernate SessionFactory и CriteriBuilder

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, criteriabuilder

Здраствуйте! Есть сущность

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ItemsStore")
public class StoredItem implements Serializable {

public StoredItem(){}

public StoredItem(HistoryBuy item){
    this.name=item.getName();
    this.appID= Integer.parseInt(item.getApp_id());
    this.author= PrivateCodes.getInstance().getAPI();
    this.price= Double.parseDouble(item.getPrice());
    this.itemID = item.getItem_id();
}

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1798070786993154676L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "itemID")
private String itemID;

@Column(name="appID")
private int appID;

@Column(name = "author")
private String author;


@Column(name = "price")
private double price;
//getter and setters...

}
```

Получаю сущности из таблицы следующим образом.

```
public List<StoredItem> getIDSByName(String name) {
        CriteriaBuilder cm = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

        CriteriaQuery<StoredItem> storedItemCriteriaQuery = cm.createQuery(StoredItem.class);
        Root<StoredItem> storedItemRoot = storedItemCriteriaQuery.from(StoredItem.class);
        storedItemCriteriaQuery.select(storedItemRoot);
        storedItemCriteriaQuery.where(cm.and(cm.equal(storedItemRoot.get("author"),this.author),cm.equal(storedItemRoot.get("name"),name)));
        return session.createQuery(storedItemCriteriaQuery).getResultList();
    }
```

Изменяю значения результата и использую в дальнейшем.

```
List<StoredItem> ids = service.getIDSByName(name);

ids.forEach(x->x.setPrice(x.getPrice()/(1.0-5.0/100)));
```

После повторного выполнения CriteriaBuilder приходят уже измененные данные. В таблице данные не меняются. Как правильно работать с результатом чтобы получать данные из таблицы, а не измененные в памяти?

Comment: Как это не меняются, откуда тогда приходят данные.

Comment: Как мне кажется из persist context. Пробовал ставить CacheMode.IGNORE. Данные все равно изменяются.

Comment: Перед повторным выполнением запроса вызвать `session.flush()`

Comment: Если нужно "отменить" последние изменения для сущности (которые ещё не сохранены в базу) `storedItem`, нужно вызвать `session.refresh(storedItem)`

Comment: Здесь надо понять, чего собственно добиваемся. Если мы загрузили данные и они попали в КЭШ сессии, то HIBERNATE отслеживает начальное сосотояние entity (в КЭШ) и текущее. Если попытаться заново загрузить этот же entity (ID) с другими данными, то вопрос чего мы хотим иметь в КЭШ (там для одного ID только одно состояние) и текущее значение - у Entity может быть только одно. Просьба продумать и написать что хочется получить.

Answer (score 0):

При очистке сессии работает корректно.

```
public List<StoredItem> getIDSByName(String name) {
    session.clear();
    CriteriaBuilder cm = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<StoredItem> storedItemCriteriaQuery = cm.createQuery(StoredItem.class);
    Root<StoredItem> storedItemRoot = storedItemCriteriaQuery.from(StoredItem.class);
    storedItemCriteriaQuery.select(storedItemRoot);
    storedItemCriteriaQuery.where(cm.and(cm.equal(storedItemRoot.get("author"),this.author),cm.equal(storedItemRoot.get("name"),name)));
    return session.createQuery(storedItemCriteriaQuery).getResultList();
}
```